# Meteor: Publishing all user not working without autopublish package

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-publications

I would to show a list of all users, in my template.
I have:

```
//publications.js
Meteor.publish('users', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: {username: 1, profile: 1} });
});

//router.js
Router.route('/users/add/:_id?', {name: 'users.add', controller: 'UserAddController'});

UserAddController = RouteController.extend({
  subscriptions: function(){
    return [ Meteor.subscribe('hospitals'), 
            Meteor.subscribe('roles'),
            Meteor.subscribe('users') ];
  },
  action: function() {
    this.render('addUser', { 
      data: function(){
        return { hospital_id : this.params._id }
      }
    });
  }
});


//client
Template.listUsers.helpers({
  users: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({});
  }
});
```

But the list keep showing only the current logged-in user. I have created a list of users using `Account.createUser()` function What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your publications.js file located? It should be in server directory.

Comment: Yes, it's in a server directory.

Comment: check your template. Also do a `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` in the browser console and see if it has all the users.

Comment: In the console, it keep showing only one, the logged in user .

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to a publication using this.subscribe() in `subscriptions` hook:

```
// a place to put your subscriptions
subscriptions: function() {
  this.subscribe('items');

  // add the subscription to the waitlist
  this.subscribe('item', this.params._id).wait();
}
```

Or use waitOn:

```
// Subscriptions or other things we want to "wait" on. This also
// automatically uses the loading hook. That's the only difference between
// this option and the subscriptions option above.
waitOn: function () {
  return Meteor.subscribe('post', this.params._id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Meteor publishes the current user. I see that you have a `addUser` template and a `listUsers` template. The problem is that while `addUser` is subscribed to the `users` publication, `listUsers` is not (this would depend on what else you have in your router of course). To fix this, change the call to `this.render` to render the `listUsers` template. Then, your `users` helper should work, and you can render the information however you like.

I tested this with my own app (the Microscope project from [DiscoverMeteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/)) and it worked for me. Hope it works for you too. Comment here if not, and be sure to accept this answer if it worked. =)